# How to log to different files based on from which python process logging is called?

Tags: python, logging, python-multiprocessing

I am working on a test framework.  Each test is launched as a new python multiprocessing process.
There is one master log file and individual log files corresponding to each test.
There is a master logger created at the launch of framework code and a new logger created in each test process.  Test loggers log to both - it's own log file and master log file.

There are multiple libraries that can be used by any of the test.
Currently there is no logging done in library function. In order to add logging to the library functions, logger object needs to passed as a parameter to this library function. To achieve this, every function signature in library modules and function call will have to be modified, which is not practical.

As I understand, I cannot have module level logger because  module level logger will log to different file for each module and not for each test process.

Can you suggest a solution where I don't have to pass log objects around function and log statements would log to the right file based on which process is calling the function?

Answer (score 0):

The [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) module has a `get_ident` member which could be used to index some logger dictionary, something like;

```
from threading import get_ident

loggers[get_ident()].logError('blah blah blah')
```

However, once you have all of this test logging throughout your libraries, how will that impact your production performance?